# Gnome-dictionary does not use German freedict dictionaries

Tags: 12.04, gnome, dictionary

First I have installed dictd and some dictionaries according to [the firs post in this topic](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-145949.html). I have installed dict-gcide & dict-wn & dict-freedict-hun-eng & dict-freedict-eng-hun. I have tried it, it is working.
After I have installed dict-freedict-deu-eng & dict-freedict-eng-deu, I have got these message:

"Setting up dict-freedict-deu-eng (1.3-4ubuntu1) ...

The parameter --locale=xx_YY.utf-8 was not set in your /etc/default/dictd,
   so after installing this package dictd may stop working.

Setting up dict-freedict-eng-deu (1.3-4ubuntu1) ...

The parameter --locale=xx_YY.utf-8 was not set in your /etc/default/dictd,
   so after installing this package dictd may stop working."

The gnome-dictionary did not search for German words, it writes: "Error while looking up definition"
After I removed the hashmark (#) before the line "DICTD_ARGS="$DICTD_ARGS --locale=en_US.utf-8"" in the file /etc/default/dictd, I have restarted the dictd service, but my attempt was not successful. I still can't search for German words in gnome-ditionary. Can anybody help me to solve this issue?
I have Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom and I managed this way.

Is your newly installed "fd-deu-eng" showing up when you type?

```
dict -I
```

If you 'apt-get remove' the successfully installed "dict-freedict-hun-eng", does 'dict -I' reflect the change? If not, then the online version of dictd may be interfering your local generic instance of dictd. Try

```
ps aux | grep dictd
```

and kill that instance, and 'dict -I' or 'dict -D' again. If you see a complete set of packages and an "On pan.alephnull.com" header, you in fact can already use

```
dict -d fd-deu-eng 'Guten Tag'
```

When offline, 'dict -I' will reveal nothing. This is the time you can

```
sudo dictd start
```

and 'dict -I' will reflect your recently installed/removed package list.